# simplest way to show/hide div that shares classes with other divs using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

say my code goes something like:

```
<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="something">sth</div>
<div class="container"><div class="content">content 01</div></div>
<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="something">sth</div>
<div class="container"><div class="content">content 02</div></div>
```

with the css being:

```
.content { display:none; }
```

but when i click one of the `.click`, i'd only like the `.content` below it to show. what's the easiest, most simplest way to do so using jquery? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just bind click event and use any relevant transversal method, e.g:

```
$('.click').on('click', function(){        
    $(this).nextAll('.container').first().children('.content').show();
});
```

Now the easiest way would be to wrap all relevant specific elements inside a common container/wrapper element, and then use:

```
$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.content').show();
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure this' the answer i'm looking for, so thank you! but, what document do i need to put in `<head>` for this to work, if i may ask?

Comment: @Ana You need if set on head section, once jQuery included: `<script>$(function($){$('.click').on('click', function(){        
    $(this).nextAll('.container').first().children('.content').show();
});});</script>`  I pass explecitely `$` to ready event in case you are using CMS as e.g wordpress removing globally `$` reference on document readyState change. See regarding `$(handler);` document ready shorthand: https://api.jquery.com/ready/  If `.click` elements are appended after DOM is ready, use delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: i'm currently testing it on jsfiddle, and it doesn't seem to work(?). what jquery library should i select?

Comment: @Ana Post your jsFiddle so i can check (and don't forget to debug it of course, checking at least for erro(s) in console)

Comment: @Ana You need to include jQuery of course: http://jsfiddle.net/myL7xvp6/1/  And if including snippet from head, should be: http://jsfiddle.net/myL7xvp6/2/